# driver requirments for a bsp. should a bsp contain drivers for devices run on spi?

Tags: linux, drivers, spi, bsp

I am developing a BSP for a Linux board. The boards contains a device which runs on SPI. can you please tell me if BSP should contain driver for that device or should I only provide SPI port driver in BSP?

Also if some device has user mode driver instead of kernel mode. Then this user mode driver will be part of BSP?